# VBA Array of picture boxes

Tags: vba

I am making a game for my intro to comp programming class, I have a 6 by 6 board where you do something different on each tile. I am currently working on a mob collision sub where if the player collides with the mob the player has to battle. Right now I have an issue with creating multiple of the same time of mob. Here is my code

```
Public Sub creeperS()

    ' Dim creeper As New PictureBox
    'This is now above so it can be used by other subs

    Dim creepercount As Integer
    creeper.Width = 32
    creeper.Height = 32

    creeper.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen

    creepercount = rand.Next(0, 36)
    If creepercount = 0 Then
        Me.Controls.Add(creeper)
        creeper.Top = 95
        creeper.Left = 84
        creeper.BringToFront()
    ElseIf creepercount = 1 Then
        Me.Controls.Add(creeper)
        creeper.Top = 95
        creeper.Left = 184
        creeper.BringToFront()
    ElseIf creepercount = 2 Then
        Me.Controls.Add(creeper)
        creeper.Top = 95
        creeper.Left = 284
        creeper.BringToFront()
    ElseIf creepercount = 3 Then
```

It does this all the way to 36, Im wondering if you can make a picture box array so i can have several of a mob on the board.

Comment: Can you post the class code? I would like to test a solution I have in mind...

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your class code, so I will try showing you a generic method to create controls and keep them in an array. In fact a Dictionary object...

Create a variable on top of your form, at the declarations side:

```
Option Explicit

Private shDict As Object
```

Then put the next code in your Form `Initialize` event:

```
 Dim i As Long, No As Long
 Dim txtBox As MSForms.TextBox
 No = 36 'your needed controls

   Set shDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For i = 84 To No * 100 Step 100
        Set txtBox = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txt_" & i)
        shDict.Add txtBox.Name, Array(txtBox, 95, i, True)
   Next i
```

Not having your class, my example code creates text boxes and fills their `Name`, `Top` and `Left` properties in a Dictionary array. It can keep objects, arrays, strings etc. I tried to use your `Top` and `Left` logic, but big part of them will not fit on the form surface...

Place a button on the form (named `btRepAll`). It will preposition all created shapes according to the values previously input in `shDict`.

```
Private Sub btRepAll_Click()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 84 To shDict.Count * 100 Step 100
      shDict("txt_" & i)(0).top = shDict("txt_" & i)(1)
      shDict("txt_" & i)(0).left = shDict("txt_" & i)(2)
  Next i
End Sub
```

I wanted to ask some other preliminary questions, to clarify myself regarding your real need, but since you did not answered a simple one and I cannot stay to much at my office, I preferred to post a generic answer. You can load as many properties as you want. Please try building something similar, able to better fit your real need.